# animation: Move element from one position to another

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to make a nice visual effect so the user can actual see that an element was been added to the waiting list.

Moved from the lovely Apple OS effects in several application like iMovie when you swap the library with the video history I'm trying to do a simple movement from a div element... but this turned out to be a little hard.

**Question** will be, does anyone know any library to do the same in a simpler/nicer way?

What I could accomplish in 5 minutes was this:

> http://jsbin.com/efihax

edit link: http://jsbin.com/efihax/edit

**My idea** is so smoothly shrink the `.hero-unit` div and make it like it's been added to the **Waiting List**

after this first 5 minutes I could see that this would be turn out nice if I started to code  an endless `animate` calls...  not a good practice.

Is there any other way? **Thought about CCS3** transitions / animations but I'm not that familiarized with it and still don't know how I could do this...

An image to show what I'm trying to accomplish with the `animate`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

- The `fadeOut` callback will be called once for each element that is faded out. Your code might run more smoothly if you dropped the callback and instead set a timeout to start executing the rest of the code only once, when the animation is timed to end.
- When you start your animation, you've set `position: absolute`, but your size and position of the element is still derived from its DOM position, so that it'll jump once you start animating these properties.

  In the timeout, try setting the start properties:

  ```
    orig
      .css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'width':orig.width(),
        'height':orig.height(),
        'left':orig.position().left,
        'top':orig.position().top
      });

    orig.empty();
  ```
- Your element currently appears below the `.waitList .label` because of its `margin`, and it appears greater than 1x1 px because of its `padding`. Try animating these as well.

[My edit of your code](http://jsbin.com/eyusis/edit#javascript,html,live)

**Update**

I realized that composite styles don't animate very well. To get a smooth transition, you'd want to animate `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` individually, rather than just `margin`, and the same with all four `padding` properties.

[My updated code](http://jsbin.com/eyusis/2/edit)

Comment: great points ... when we're "blind" with something, we simply don't see the obvious :o) thxs!

Comment: @balexandre: glad to help. don't miss my update for some added points.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't animate the container. Just by changing the animated element to "container" the item did fade completely. Work around it for a while and it will work.